# C++ delete[] crash

Tags: c++, crash, delete-operator

Program crashes when I'm trying to `delete[]` an array that was allocated with `new[]`. I don't see any reasons why this shouldn't work. The array is allocated in method and deleted in the end of it, it's local, everything should be fine, but it's not.
I don't see any exception name that was thrown in debug, that's why I don't know where to dig.
Through debug I see that crash is happening at first `delete[]` operator.
Without those two `delete`s no crashes happening, but I don't want something to float in memory.

```
void Atbash::EncryptString(string t)
{
    char *cOriginalString;
    char *cEncryptedString;
    unsigned int originalStringLength;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned short j = 0;

    originalString = t;
    originalStringLength = originalString.length();

    cOriginalString = new char(originalStringLength + 1);
    cEncryptedString = new char(originalStringLength + 1);

    strcpy_s(cOriginalString, originalStringLength + 1, originalString.c_str());

    cOriginalString[originalStringLength] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < originalStringLength; i++)
    {
        while (cOriginalString[i] != alphabet[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        cEncryptedString[i] = alphabet[N - j - 2];
        j = 0;
    }

    cEncryptedString[originalStringLength] = '\0';

    encryptedString = cEncryptedString;

    delete[] cOriginalString;
    delete[] cEncryptedString;
}
```

`originalString` and `encryptedString` are of "string" type.

Comment: Why are you using `char` pointers anyway?  Why not stick with `std::string` throughout that function?  Then you don't need to worry about `delete []`.

Comment: `cOriginalString = new char(originalStringLength + 1);` -- Also, explain what that does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I must work with every char idnividually further, that's why I'm converting string to char array. And that command allocates enough to convert string to char array with '\0'.

Comment: *I must work with every char idnividually further* -- So you believe that you can't work with individual characters in a `std::string`?  If so, you're wrong.  So basically you wrote buggy code for no reason.

Comment: [Same basic code, no char pointers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4dbb1039b2626c7)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, you are right. I'm migrating from C and thought that I can't work with string like with char array. My bad, forgot to check it.

Comment: A `std::string` is nothing more than a container of `char` values, no different than an array of `char` internally.  The only difference is that `std::string` is a class that contains functions that manipulate the internal array of `char`.  If `std::string` were coded so that you couldn't use the individual characters, it would be practically worthless.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I can't argue with it, a lot of redundant code. But now I'm interested what happens if I'm allocating memory that wrong way. There's allocating some chars, but not as array, right? Or that's undefined behavior?

Comment: When allocating, it is all contiguous memory.  So it is basically an "array".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, array that can't be deleted with delete[], because it was allocated not with [] but with ()?

Comment: It's simple -- if you allocate with `new` you deallocate with `delete`, allocate with `new[]`, deallocate with `delete[]`.

Comment: A tip: you could have removed most of that code and still gotten the problem. With les s code, you might have seen it yourself. That’s basic debugging technique: remove stuff until the problem goes away, then add back the thing you just removed. Repeat until done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't allocating a `char[]`, just a plain old `char`. Note that you should be using square braces (`[]`) and not parenthethis (`()`):

```
cOriginalString = new char[originalStringLength + 1];
// Here ------------------^------------------------^

cEncryptedString = new char[originalStringLength + 1];
// And here ---------------^------------------------^
```

Comment: That's where the problem is, right. Just edited it. Okay, one more question. What happens if I'm allocating like before? I'm allocating a lot of chars but not in array, right?

Comment: No, you allocated a **single** char with the value you had in the parenthesis. So then when you accessed the array it was actually undefined behaviour. You could have also experienced segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

You can process individual characters in a std::string and it will both simplify your code and make it more robust.  Here is one possible implementation.

```
void Atbash::EncryptString(string originalString)
{
    encryptedString.clear();
    encryptedString.reserve(originalString.size());

    for (auto ch:originalString)
    {
        auto index= alphabet.find(ch);
        if (index != npos)
            encryptedString += alphabet[N - index - 2];
    }
}
```